# Groovy unable to resolve class but works in groovyconsole

Tags: groovy, gradle, import, groovy-console

Trying to import the *gpars* withPool method into my project. The import works in *groovyconsole* but not when building in gradle.

Both *groovyconsole* and gradle are running groovy version 2.4.5

Any ideas?

**Groovy Console**

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
withPool(2) { (1..5).collectParallel { println it.toString() } }
```

Output:

```
1
3
2
4
5
Result: [null, null, null, null, null]
```

**Gradle compileGroovy**

Same import step as above:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
```

Gradle output:

```
:compileGroovystartup failed:
C:\Programming\Projects\groovy\src\main\groovy\lib.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class groovyx.gpars.GParsPool
 @ line 18, column 1.
   import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
   ^

1 error

 FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to import something into your build script, then you have to provide it as a build script dependency, in order to make Gradle know, where to find it, just like:

```
buildscript {    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.codehaus.gpars', name: 'gpars', version: '1.1.0'
    }
}

import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool
```

Comment: Thanks. This did fix it. The reason i didn't add to the dependency is it just worked in groovyconsole out of the box ??

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the location where groovy is installed - might be under `$GROOVY_HOME` and list the folders you'll notice the `lib` folder. Listing the content of the `lib` folder shows that `gpars-1.2.1.jar` is present there (groovy v2.4.5).

All these jar file located in `lib` folder are added to classpath when groovy is started via *groovysh* or *groovyConsole*.

However this doesn't happen when it comes to gradle and as @Stanislav answered you need to add it to classpath manually.